# Error: "no match for operator+" , for list iterator

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

For the code below, i am getting the error in title for line

```
while((*(It2 + code)).exists){
```

```
void locatetohashtable(std::list<Element> elist,
                       int *m,std::list<Element>& table,
                       std::list<std::string>& keylist )
{        
    std::list<Element>::iterator It2=table.begin();
    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    std::list<Element>::iterator It;
    for(It = elist.begin(); It != elist.end(); ++It)
    {
        int code=hash_func(stringIntValue((*It).name),*m,i);
        while((*(It2 + code)).exists){
            i++;
        }
        table.insert(*(It2+i), (*It));
        keylist.insert(keylist.begin(),(*It).name);
        k++;
    }
}
```

I am not getting the same error for `++It`

What is the problem about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An `iterator` for an `std::list` is bidirectional, so it does not support `+(int)`. The only supported move operations are `++` and `--`.

Answer (score 10):

That is because `std::list`'s iterators are [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), so they don't support the addition operation you are trying to perform. In practice, this is because it cannot be implemented as an efficient operation, since lists do not provide random access, so you'd have to step in single increments from initial iterator to the target one. The design decision is to not provide an operation what will be inefficient.

You can use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) or [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to avoid writing your own increment loops, but under the hood it will increment step by step.

Answer (score 4):

`std::list` iterators are only bidirectional, not random access, so you can't use operator `+` to advance them. Use `std::next` (C++11) or `std::advance` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of "Concept".

A `list` can only be traversed efficiently [forward and backward](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ReversibleContainer.html), thus its iterators model the Bidirectional Iterator concept.

You can either use `std::advance` to move the iterator by several positions at once, however it will not be efficient.

Or you can change to use a `vector` or `deque` instead of a list. Since they are Random Access containers, their iterators support addition and subtraction efficiently.