# C++: iterator - list.begin() throws an error

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm trying to get the index of an iterator of a list, I've read [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152986/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-the-index-of-an-iterator-of-an-stdvector) and tried the following code:

```
std::list<int> v;
std::list<int>::iterator iter = v.insert(v.begin(), 1);
int i = iter - v.begin();
```

Surprisingly it doesn't work, I got an error.

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
```

What's the problem? How to make it work?

Comment: Have you read the answer of the question from link mention by you? Accepted answer says it all.

Comment: You have the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564222/error-no-match-for-operator-for-list-iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v.insert` returns a list iterator, that list iterator only satisfies [*BiDirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). That means that `operator-` isn't defined for it.

To get the distance you can use `std::distance` instead:

```
int diff = std::distance(v.begin(), iter);
```

Answer (score 3):

List container iterators are not random access iterators and therefore don't provide substration. You can use `std::distance` to obtain index.