# c++ std::list compile issue? related to list.end() and list.end() - 1

Tags: c++, list

In below code.

```
int main() {
    list<int> m_list;
    m_list.push_back(1);
    list<int>::iterator it1 = (--m_list.end());   // it works, *it1 return 1;
    list<int>::iterator it2 = (m_list.end() - 1); // compile issue? 
}
```

Anybody explain why in list (m_list.end() - 1) has compile issue? and why (--m_list.end()) is OK?
If we change to others, vector, string. both cases do work.

```
int main() {
    vector<int> m_vector;
    m_vector.push_back(1);
    vector<int>::iterator it1 = (--m_vector.end());   // both work
    vector<int>::iterator it2 = (m_vector.end() - 1); // both work 
}
```

Comment: Related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564222/error-no-match-for-operator-for-list-iterator

Comment: `list<T>` does not have random access iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anybody explain why in list (m_list.end() - 1) has compile issue?

Because list iterator doesn't support random access. Only random access iterators are guaranteed to support `operator-` (and `operator+`).

> and why (--m_list.end()) is OK?

Because bidirectional iterators support `operator--` (and `operator++`). List iterator is bidirectional.

> If we change to others, vector, string. both cases do work.

Both vector and string have random access iterators.

Comment: Amazing answer.

Answer (score 6):

The reason behind this is that list::end() returns a **bidirectional iterator** which does not support such operation.

Source:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/

On the other hand, vector::end() and string::end() returns a **random access iterator** which supports such operation.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/

**Edit:**

If you really want to accomplish the task, use `std::prev()` function

```
list<int>::iterator it2 = (std::prev(m_list.end(), 1));
```

As suggested by [Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker), "The second argument to std::prev has a default of 1"

So, you may do this also:

```
list<int>::iterator it2 = (std::prev(m_list.end()));
```

Comment: The second argument to `std::prev` has a default of 1, so all that’s needed is `std::prev(m_list.end())`.

Comment: Thanks @PeteBecker for your suggestion. Your point has been included in the answer.